# Option to delete your own question

Tags: feature-request, specific-question, vote-to-delete

I want to rid this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189934/209665) of mine. Since it is put on hold, I can not delete it. No need of showing it, so I am suggesting that even if the questions are on hold, a user having the ability to delete his questions is more friendly.

Comment: It has been deleted...

Comment: @jeffreylin_ It still show on google search. In stackoverflow, not meta , when it is deleted it goes away.

Comment: @LazyNinja: We can't control how long Google keeps something in its cache after it gets deleted. It *is* deleted, and Google will be shown a 404 page if it attempts to access the page.

Comment: @animuson, thank you for pointing that out. It could be a cache problem.

Comment: It's too late. NSA already knows about your question.

Comment: @LazyNinja [**HERE**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663688) See: *"Remove content that’s not live"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if questions are on-hold, they can still be good for SEO, and more people will be directed towards the right answer (if it was closed as duplicate).

Comment: That's right, in case of closed as duplicated. But this kind of questions won't benefit anyone in the long run.

Comment: Keywords. If one question has 'a' and one is 'b' I can search for both a and b and still arrive at the same answer.

Comment: We actually do delete questions/answers, and permit not only the original poster and moderators, but also some higher-reputation users to do so. We don't always *want* certain posts drawing people here; for instance, if someone make a lot of posts about baking cakes, we would have no interest in the traffic which resulted from that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber but I want cake

Comment: @AaronBertrand [This might help](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cake?sort=votes&pagesize=15) ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber sounds a whole lot better than [Looking for meat ingredient suggestions for a Yoghurt Cake recipe](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27773/looking-for-meat-ingredient-suggestions-for-a-yoghurt-cake-recipe).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am not even clicking that link, even if I have faith in the baseline quality of it due to it being on SE, that title just... **no**!

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'll be honest, I was expecting some lewd answers, but in the end I gagged in my mouth a little for the more innocent reason.

Comment: @AaronBertrand bacon cake sounds good, don't knock it till you try it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand bacon cake IS awesome... have tried it!